# Another way to do cleanup in C?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, free, atexit

Consider this program:

```
int main(void)
{
    int* i = malloc(sizeof(int));
    int* j = malloc(sizeof(int));
}
```

However this is a naive approach, because `malloc` may fail and the pointers are not `free`'d.

So you can do this:

```
int main(void)
{
    int* i; 
    int* j;

    if ((i = malloc(sizeof(int)) < 0)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    if ((j = malloc(sizeof(int)) < 0)
    {
        free(i);
        return -1;
    }

    free(i);
    free(j);
}
```

However I consider this very error-prone. Consider having to assign 20 pointers, in the last `malloc` error case, you have to `free` 19 variables and then `return -1`.

I also know `atexit`, which can help me to write it like this:

```
int* i; 
int* j;

void del_i(void)
{
    free(i);
}

void del_j(void)
{
    free(j);
}

int main(void)
{
    if ((i = malloc(sizeof(int)) < 0)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        atexit(del_i);
    }

    if ((j = malloc(sizeof(int)) < 0)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        atexit(del_j);
    }
}
```

Which is better, but I dislike having to declare all pointers as global. Is there some way to combine these two approaches, basically:

1. Having destructors for pointers, which can be either executed directly or be used with `atexit`.
2. Having pointers local to functions.

Comment: I don't get your point. If you're finishing/stopping the execution of the program, why bother about `free()`?

Comment: 1. You should always `free` pointers. 2. Consider this in the context of a larger program

Comment: Thanks for enlightening me, but i'll stick to my version. :)

Comment: Negative return values of a program are typically reserved for the system. An application should use small positive values and `0`.

Comment: malloc will return either `NULL` or a valid pointer.  Checking for *"less than 0"* ( `< 0`) make no sense at all.

Comment: One thing to be aware of is that there may be a limited number of `atexit` slots (but at least 32).

Comment: "Having destructors for pointers" - if you want C++ features, why not use C++?

Answer (score 4):

`free` on `NULL` is defined to be a safe no-op. So a non-jumping variation could be:

```
int *i = malloc(sizeof(int)); 
int *j = malloc(sizeof(int));

if(i && j)
{
    // do some work
}

free(i);
free(j);
```

Answer (score 3):

First, this will *not* detect `malloc` failure:

```
if ((i = malloc(sizeof(int)) < 0)
{
    return -1;
}
```

`malloc` returns `NULL` on failure, not a negative number.

Second, `atexit` is good for cleaning up static and global objects. It is not a good idea to make local objects global only to use them inside `atexit`.

A better approach is to make a `struct` for all related pointers that you need to allocate in an all-or-nothing unit, define a function for freeing them all at once, and write a function that allocates them one by one with memory checking on each allocation:

```
typedef struct AllOrNothing {
    double *dPtr;
    int *iPtr;
    float *fPtr;
    size_t n;
} AllOrNothing;

void freeAllOrNothing(AllOrNothing *ptr) {
    free(ptr->dPtr);
    free(ptr->iPtr);
    free(ptr->fPtr);
    free(ptr);
}

int allocateAllOrNothing(size_t n, AllOrNothing **res) {
    *res = malloc(sizeof(AllOrNothing));
    if (*res == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }
    // Freeing NULL is allowed by the standard.
    // Set all pointers to NULL upfront, so we can free them
    // regardless of the stage at which the allocation fails
    (*res)->dPtr = NULL;
    (*res)->iPtr = NULL;
    (*res)->fPtr = NULL;
    (*res)->n = n;
    (*res)->dPtr = malloc(n*sizeof(double));
    if ((*res)->dPtr == NULL) {
        free(*res);
        *res = NULL;
        return -1;
    }
    (*res)->fPtr = malloc(n*sizeof(float));
    if ((*res)->fPtr == NULL) {
        free(*res);
        *res = NULL;
        return -1;
    }
    (*res)->iPtr = malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    if ((*res)->iPtr == NULL) {
        free(*res);
        *res = NULL;
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(void)
{
int* i = NULL; // Init with NULL otherwise free on none NULL possible
int* j = NULLL;

if (!(i = malloc(sizeof(int)))
{
    goto exit;
}
if (!(j = malloc(sizeof(int)))
{
    goto exit;
}
...
exit:
    free(i);
    free(j);
    ...
    return err;
}
```

This is something you can solve with goto statements.

Comment: You jump to `exit` when the allocations succeed. Not so helpful.

Comment: Just be wary of http://www.dwheeler.com/essays/apple-goto-fail.html -type mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(void)
{
    int* i = NULL; 
    int* j = NULL;
    bool success = false;

    do {
        i = malloc(sizeof(int));
        if (NULL == i) break;

        j = malloc(sizeof(int));
        if (NULL == j) break;

        success = true;
    } while (0);

    if (!success)
    {
        printf("Something failed!");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("All succeeded!");
        // Do more work
    }

    free(i);
    free(j);
    return (success? 0 : 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid multiple exit points.  Avoid interlacing allocation and error handling.  Follows a clean order of operation:

1. Declare, allocate  and initialize resources..
2. If all successful, do the task.
3. Clean-up.
4. Return status.

---

```
 // Do all allocations first, test their `NULL`-ness, then free them all.
 int main(void) {
    // Allocate resources   
    // declare and allocate in one step
    int* i    = malloc(sizeof *i);
    double* j = malloc(sizeof *j);

    // Test for acceptability
    bool ok = i && j;

    // Perform the main body of code
    if (ok) {
      ; // do normal process in the code;
    }

    // free resources
    free(i);
    free(j);

    // return status
    return ok ? 0 : -1;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    int *i=NULL,*j=NULL;

    if(!(i=malloc(sizeof(int))))
            goto EXIT;
    if(!(j=malloc(sizeof(int))))
            goto EXIT;
    /* do some work */
    return 0;
    EXIT:
            free(i);
            free(j);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

Although goto is considered a bad programming practice
but here we can use it to get our task done with ease and simplicity